# ImageMagick Error in Django's aino-convert app

Tags: django, imagemagick

I'm using [aino-convert](http://bitbucket.org/aino/aino-convert/src) on a project and running into an issue I've never seen before. I've taken the exact same code from another project where I've used aino-convert, but it's blowing up with an ImageMagick error in the new project. My template code looks like this:

```
{% thumbnail img.image "156x106" as thumb %}
<img src="{{ thumb }}" alt="{{ img.name }}" />
```

and that results in the following TemplateSyntaxError:

Caught ExecuteException while rendering: Magick: invalid argument for option `-resize': '156x106' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/2343.

I've tried playing around with the sizes to see if it was an issue with the source image. I've tried removing the quotation marks and not aliasing the result to a variable, but it all results in that same error. I'm running ImageMagick 6.6.2 on Windows, also seeing the error on the live Linux server.

Comment: what if you use `{% convert img.image "-resize 156x106" as thumb %}`, is it buggy too?

Comment: .. or you might try just `"156x"` or `"x106"`

Comment: The convert syntax works. Huh. Want to repost that as an answer so I can credit you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make sure that the `x` character in size option `"156x106"` is really lower case letter `x` and not e.g. multiplication sign `×`

#### UPDATE

alternatively, you can try using different syntax:

```
{% convert img.image "-resize 156x106" as thumb %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure Django Template Engine is not interpreting the `x` in `156x106` as hexa-decimal?

That way by the thin aino (or convert) gets the resize options it's all screwed up. This could cause the problem.